# Non-exhaustive patterns in recursive length function

Tags: function, haskell, multiline, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

I'm new to the Haskell language and doing an exercise of the book Get programming with Haskell, I tried the following function:

```haskell
myLength [] = 0
myLength (x:xs) = 1 + myLength xs
```

But throws the exception: `Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLength` when calling the function with all patterns:

- an empty array
- an array of just one item
- with more items.

I'm using GHCi, version 8.0.2 and the book uses Haskell version 8.0.1.

I'm not so sure about what case isn't being covered, sorry I'm very new to haskell and I'll be great to know what piece is missing.

Comment: You are probably running this in `ghci`, then you need to define it in a multiline statement.

Comment: The linked duplicate is about GHCi and `let`. Even if you're not using `let` in GHCi, it's implicit, so the same answers apply.

Comment: Yeah the problem was solved when I added the functions on their own source file and loaded it on ghci, thanks! that was a silly mistake.